# Web Platforms - Amount of Control Given between Java vs ASP.Net

Tags: java, asp.net, iis, tomcat, windows-server-2008

I've been doing a lot of research on web platforms (mainly .Net vs Java), and have found that both seem to serve a lot of purposes. What I'd like to know is, does ASP.Net provide enough control, flexibility, and customization in terms of how the server hosts and runs the website, or does Java with, say, Tomcat and Swing or Struts2 offer more flexibility?

Since Tomcat is from Apache, I'd imagine that they implemented the same design and methodology which came from Apache (which I do like). I question whether or not IIS and Windows Server actually provide this sort of thing. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Voted to close as 'Not a real question' as this is a discussion topic that doesn't fit the Q&A model of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my own personal analysis of a comparison of the two frameworks having worked on .NET for 4 years and Java for around 5 years.

NET has a cookie-cutter like development stack. Java you have a bit more freedom. This can be a positive or a negative depending upon the developer preference. In other words, if you want to do something in .NET there is typically one standard way of doing so. This is not the case with Java where you can choose from a myriad of libraries and/or strategies to complete your task. In my opinion, Java tends to cater to a more skilled community (especially, since almost every major university teaches on Java) that has a bit more confidence and ability when designing/building applications. That is not a generalization of all Java EE vs. .NET developers as I've met equal talents in skill and ability on both platforms, I'm making a generalization of the larger community as a whole. At the end of the day, it is a harder environment to setup and run, but with that comes the added flexibility.

As far as server environments go, you can host Java EE apps on a number of servers (Tomcat, Glassfish/Apache, JBoss, etc..). Most of them open source, so if you're skilled enough, you can dig down into that code and figure out exactly what you're getting and modify it if necessary. This is absolutely not the case with the Microsoft environment. You basically have a windows server running IIS and that's pretty much it. IIS is a decent web hosting tool in my opinion. It's easy to learn the basics, however out of the box it does not have anywhere near the customization and configuration that you can setup with Apache. For example, you have to install Helicon(or some other tool) as an add-on to IIS if you want to create complex Rewrite rules for your site. Rewrite rules are easily implemented in Apache as a standard.

In conclusion, a Java web environment is harder to setup and support, but you'll get that added flexibility with your language and your server environment as you gain more knowledge.

Comment: This is the type of answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing a platform should be really about your available expertise - your own or whatever resources you (will) have.

If you know the platform you can make it fly. As @iamkrillin stated, I too have yet to hit a roadblock with IIS/.Net platform. This is true whether or not I am hosting the site myself (colo - I own hardware/OS, etc) or via a hosting provider. On Windows hosting though, choose wisely if you host. If you know you need some bare metal access then make sure you get that privilege from whomever you choose to host with. A good practice is to set your application to **medium-trust** while developing - unless you will go for a dedicated server, this will likely be your hosting provider's application security setting on shared/cloud environments.

As far as routing is concerned (brought up by @GeorgeMcDowd), IIS now has it bolted in, or, if you prefer to do this at the (ASP.Net) application level (instead of IIS), you can do that too (RouteTables). I don't know how complex you envision your routes will be, so I can't tell whether you will run into some limitation either of these options offer.

As far as "standard" or "cookie cutter" is concerned, I'm not actually sure what that means. You have a (massive and growing) .Net base library (from Microsoft). If you need something very specialized (and not offered by the base lib), you can scour Codeplex and other sources (too) for libraries that you can use in your application. If you use Visual Studio, you can use NuGet to do this with a few clicks.

Don't take Microsoft's stewardship of .Net lightly as well. It's consistently being improved, updated **by Microsoft**.

There is an area where Microsoft is critically lagging though - and that is in mobile. Against Android and IOS and their respective devices, its a tough climb for Windows (phone, Windows 8 tablet, etc.). There are however, tools that allow you to develop in .Net and push to either device. I am only personally beginning to get into that so I cannot say how perfect or disastrous it is.

Just about the only thing left is cost. Its still cheaper to host on non-Windows platforms. If you already have expertise in non-Windows platforms, then its a no-brainer. However, the hosting cost difference shouldn't be your deciding factor if you have a learning curve (that is commonly the hidden cost).

Comment: Great answer, and well objective analysis. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Without a specific example of what you are referring to configuration wise.  I feel pretty comforable saying that there are a variety of ways to configure a website and how it is hosted/ran etc from within the IIS control panel.  To that end, I have never ran into a situation where I thought "I wish I could do x with my website" and was not able to make IIS do it.